# Event for adding or removing objects to a List

Tags: c#, list, events, generics

I am working on a control to draw some graphs. For this purpose I want to derive a control from `PictureBox` and add a field to it which basically a List of following simple class:

```
public class Curve
{
     public List<PointF> DataPoints;
     public Color CurveColor;
     //and constructor and stuff
}
```

And the PictureBox  class:

```
public class Graph : PictureBox
{
    List<Curve> Curves;
    //And some code to take care of drawing the curves
}
```

So I really apriciate some tips here, is there a way to hook up an event so whenever a `Curve` object is being added or removed in the `Graph` class, it redraws itself with remaining curve objects?

I found some details here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) but this is for `ArrayList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to use an ObservableCollection into your Graph class then listen to its CollectionChanged Event to Redraw your Graph.

```
public class Graph : PictureBox {
    ObservableCollection<Point> Curves;
    //And some code to take care of drawing the curves

    public Graph() {
      Curves.CollectionChanged += Curves_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void Curves_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
      Redraw();
    }
}
```